# $in query operator not working in aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection of dataset, which I would like to run some custom queries using mongo aggregation framework.

I am trying to do the following

`minLimit` and `maxLimit` are date objects to specify date range.

```
Tickets.aggregate(
{ $match: { timestamp: { $gte: minLimit, $lte: maxLimit } } },
{ $match: { staffId: { $in: staffIds } } }

).allowDiskUse(true).exec(cb);
```

If I don't include staff match condition the above is working fine but after I include staff match condition no records are returned.

The `staffIds` is a array of ids which I get using lodash pluck method.
First I get all staff documents using

```
Staff.find({some filter condition}, callback);
```

Then I pluck each of the records using

```
var staffIds = _.pluck(results, '_id');
```

I will pass this staffIds to match condition.

1. Why it is not working? If I remove $in match it is working fine.

Comment: Can you try to match only `{ $match: { staffId: { $in: staffIds } } }`, if it still no result you may need to look at your `staffIds` array is in same format as `Staff._id` (may be in `ObjectId` format). Last is to check `Staff._id` in `staffIds`  are match with the given timestamp :).

Comment: Yes, even single match is not working. I checked the staff._id is in ObjectId format and staffIds is in string format. So do I have to convert each of ids into ObjectId

Comment: Oops, hope this is too late :) and Yes!! you should convert those ids into ObjectId :).